# Thymeleaf and Vuejs integration error in special attributes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, thymeleaf

Anyone already encountered the error when using special attributes for HTML tags via thymeleaf?

Example:
Thymeleaf will be using this HTML code,

```
<div class="draggable-header-view"
    @mousedown="startDrag" @touchstart="startDrag"
    @mousemove="onDrag" @touchmove="onDrag"
    @mouseup="stopDrag" @touchend="stopDrag" @mouseleave="stopDrag">
</div>
```

`@mousedown` etc are also used by vuejs.

However, when Thymeleaf will use this HTML code, Exception parsing document will occur.

My guess is that `@` in Thymeleaf is a reserved keyword.  It is used for `@{value}`.However, `@` is also used for vuejs.

Has someone been able to do some workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, it is somewhat unclear which library you are asking about, and what your problem is. Please edit your question to make it clearer and add additional details as to what your having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what is that tech you are using, but if it's only a forbidden `@` problem as you suggest, be aware that it's just a shortcut for `v-on:`.

So you should be able to write it this way:

```
<div class="draggable-header-view"
    v-on:mousedown="startDrag" v-on:touchstart="startDrag"
    v-on:mousemove="onDrag" v-on:touchmove="onDrag"
    v-on:mouseup="stopDrag" v-on:touchend="stopDrag"
    v-on:mouseleave="stopDrag">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot.  I didn't know that @ was the shortcut for v-on:.  My code runs okay now.

Comment: If this answer is fixing the problem, then I guess you can label it as accepted! :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to accept. It's my first time posting here in stackoverflow